# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] en Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo este error en *node*,

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

He estado buscando por aquí y he visto que tiene ver con la escritura de la cabecera, pero no sé cómo aplicar la solución. Es un ejercicio que estoy haciendo en *node*, donde hago un *login artesal* en un *loginController* y luego redirecciono a un *crudController* para acceder a un *dashboard* y ver un *crud* de usuarios, os dejo las las funciones implicadas:

```js
// Este es el método que hace la comprobación del login y si es correcta redirecciono al crud y dentro del siguiente método donde me da el error.
function validarLogin(req, res) {
  console.log(database);
  pool.query(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?",
    [req.body.email, req.body.password],
    (error, result) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      var resultado = result;
      if (resultado.length > 0) {
        res.redirect("/showAll");
      } else {
        console.log("Login incorrecto");
        res.render("errorLogin", {
          datos: null,
          estado: false,
        });
      }
    }
  );
}

// Aquí justo me da el error cuando quiero hacer el render y pasarle los resultados de la consulta donde van todos los usuarios.
function showAll(req, res) {
  pool.query("SELECT * FROM users;", (error, result) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    var resultado = result;
    console.log(resultado);
    if (resultado.length > 0) {
      console.log(resultado);
      res.render("dashboard", {
        datos: resultado,
        estado: false,
      });
    } else {
      console.log("No hay datos que mostrar");
      res.render("mostrar", {
        datos: null,
        estado: false,
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: por qué  `nuresultado`? no debiese ser `resultado`? De paso, pon por favor la traza completa del error para ver de dónde viene el llamado

Comment: Era una errata, modificado gracias

Answer (score 0):

Aventurando una posible causa, tienes que mirar en tu traza de error para saber dónde se gatilla el error. Hasta ahora sabes que ocurre en `showAll` pero no en qué parte de ella.

Cuando express termina con los headers da vuelta la página y de ahí en adelante empieza a escribir el body, siendo los primeros inmodificables. Al mismo tiempo, cuando haces `throw error` dentro de un callback eso no lo recibe el handler de Express, que está pensado para capturar errores en el scope principal de una ruta, o bien manejarlos cuando se pasa `next(err)` (que pienso es lo más apropiado en tu caso). Tirar un error en un callback de la ruta es atrapado por el evento `uncaughtException` que está en otra capa.

Me da la impresión de que el error recorre el stack aguas arriba mientras el flujo dentro del callback sigue adelante hasta el último `res.render`, el cual convierte los headers en inmutables, y cuando el `uncaughtException` finalmente recibe el evento, un tick más tarde (porque eso ocurre en cualquier callback aunque no haya espera) intenta fijar el statusCode a 500 y se produce la falla que ves.

Yo probaría con

```
function showAll(req, res, next) {
  pool.query("SELECT * FROM users;", (error, result) => {
    if (error) return next(error);
    ... el resto
  }
}
```

con lo cual te aseguras de no seguir de largo y en cambio pasar el control al siguiente middleware (y si no hay uno declarado, significa pasarlo al errorHandler de express).